# Pyserial write sending empty value to device.Teraterm sending proper value

Tags: python, embedded, pyserial, teraterm

I am using pyserial as well as teraterm to communicate with my device.I need to pass a hex value to my device when it asks for it.So,I am reading the port continuously and then when the device asks for the value,I write to the port.Using teraterm I copy the value into the terminal and press enter, the value gets accepted by the device.But while using pyserial empty value is getting passed even though the device receives the value successfully.

Here is my python code:

```py
with serial.Serial( 
            port = com_port,
            baudrate = 115200,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            timeout = 1,
            xonxoff = False,
            rtscts = False,
            dsrdtr = False
        ) as ser:
             while True:
                line = ser.readline().strip()
                line = line.decode('utf-8')
                if line and len(line)>0:
                    print(line)
                    downlink = 'ABCD\r\n'
                    if 'Waiting for Downlink Timeout' in line:
                        time.sleep(2)
                        print(ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode('utf-8'))
                        ser.write(downlink.encode())
                        time.sleep(2)
```

**Screenshots from teraterm:**

Teraterm settings

[image: Teraterm settings]

Asking for downlink

[image: Asking for downlink]

Downlink received successfully

[image: Downlink received successfully]

Downlink not received

[image: Downlink not received]

**Screenshots from python console:**

Asking for downlink

[image: Asking for downlink]

Empty downlink received

[image: Empty downlink received]

Comment: To me the Python script looks as if you're not sending hex values but a string, in the example "ABCD", which by accident consists of hex digits.

Comment: I am encoding it to bytes and sending it.It doesn't matter if it's hex or not.I am also sending the same value through tera term,which is getting sent.

Comment: Grab an oscilloscope or a protocol analyzer and check the serial line from the PC to device. Since there are only 6 characters sent, you should be able to easily spot a difference between your two methods.

Comment: If it was raw hex then Teraterm would have displayed it as gibberish, since it doesn't support hex.